# Specifying resource when migrating from Tomcat to Weblogic 10.3

Tags: tomcat, migration, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

We are trying to migrate from Tomcat 6.0 to Weblogic 10.3. In the Tomcat server directory, .../conf/context.xml we have specified something like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MSSQL1" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mssql1.dev.abc.xyz.com/db_name"
              username="usr" password="pwd$"
              initialSize="10" maxActive="10" maxIdle="10"
maxWait="-1"/>
```

I suppose we have to add something similar to the Weblogic server as well. But I am not sure where/in which file we have to do so. Can anyone please help me with this?

I am completely new to the Weblogic 10.3, have never used this or any of its previous versions before. So please pardon me if I am asking a very basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little research helped.

On the Weblogic Admin Console:

Services->Data Sources

- New Data Sources, in my case 'Generic Data Source'
- Specify any name, then a JNDI name and select Database Type, in my case MS SQL Server
- Next, select appropriate driver
  Standard drivers provided by Weblogic:
- XA: weblogic.jdbcx.sqlserver.SQLServerDataSource
- Non-XA: weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver 
  If you using transaction, use 1 otherwise use 2
  Click Next, Next
- Define Connection Properties.
- Do Test Connection

Done!